# Feed Python output to Unity3D

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have some code that is running in the python console reading out text lines.

Is it possible to feed the output of the python console to my Unity3D game script so that it can trigger some actions in my game?

in other words:
python console running in the background outputs commands that need to feed to my Unity game.

Comment: What Python console? Did you embed Python in your app? If not, did you mean the regular command prompt / Terminal app? Or a command window that you launch from within your app but is an external process?

Comment: I did not embed python in my app. This is just the windows terminal output that i would like to feed to unity. This is external of the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient solution would be to use TCP sockets in both the Python script and the Unity-side script. Since the Python-side is *serving* the data, then designate it as the server socket and make the socket on the Unity-side the client. This solution will be much faster than writing and reading to a shared file.

Comment: Thanks, this is exact path I was on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows you can use Process, spin up python and read standard out and collect the output.  Out side of that, if the process isn't started in Unity, you best bet is probably to monitor a file in a particular directory for changes and read in those changes which would have been the output from your python console.

[Here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-run-or-remote-external-program-within-unity-editor.48697/) is an example of UnityScript creating and executing a process.